# Writing, merging and sorting values in text file using python

Tags: python

I am getting values from a .dat file and writing those values in a txt file. The problem is there are values that repeat. Here is the example output in the txt file:

```
1001   
1002   
1003   
1003   
1004   
1005
```

How do I remove or merge the 1003 value and save it in the new txt file I created? Here is my current code:

```
for line in fi:
    if "CA002" in line:
        txt = fi.next()
        print txt #view values

        file = open("Reference.txt", "a+")
        file.write(txt)
try:
    read = file.readlines()
    read = list(set(read))
    read.sort()
    print read
finally:
    file.close()
```

I'm not actually sure if what I wrote does. Some say to use the set() function to merge repeating values. But I don't think it does the job. Any suggestions? Forgive my code, I have only started to learn the basics of python. Thanks!

The end result should be something like this in the text file:

```
1001   
1002   
1003   
1004   
1005
```

Comment: Please describe in detail how you want the output file (or files, if there is more than on) shall look as the result.

Comment: Do those repeated values appear continuously or not?

Comment: Is the order of the numbers important?

Comment: @dragon2fly yes they appear continuously.

Comment: @Tichodroma the output file should be in a txt file. All repeating values should be merged into one and all values should be in order. I didn't include in the post on how I was getting data from a dat file. I just showed how I was collecting the values and saving them into a new txt file.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Not in every case but it would be helpful to have a additional function like that

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `set` container for check the duplicate then write to file,also as a more pythonic way use `with` to open your file and don't use python types name as your variable name!:

```
with open("Reference.txt", "a+") as f,open("input.dat") as fi :
    seen=set()
    for line in fi:
        if "CA002" in line:
            txt = fi.next()
            print txt #view values
            seen.add(txt)
            if not txt in seen :
                f.write(txt)
```

If you are in 2.6 you can not use `With` statement with more than one item,so you can do :

```
with open("Reference.txt", "a+") as f :
   with open("input.dat") as fi:
        seen=set()
        for line in fi:
            if "CA002" in line:
                txt = fi.next()
                print txt #view values
                seen.add(txt)
                if not txt in seen :
                    f.write(txt)
```

Comment: There is no need to keep opening the file, open it once at the beginning.

Comment: don't forget to open the .dat either ;)

Comment: By the way I'm using python 2.6 so there might be a problem with the multiple context manager in the with statement

Comment: @albert3003 Yeah in python 2.6 its unable! checkout the edit!

Answer (score 2):

Use `with` to open your files, don't keeps opening the file and appending, open it once outside the loop. You can use an OrderedDict and a generator expression to write unique elements and keep order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("input.dat") as f, open("Referenced.txt","w") as out:
    filtered = OrderedDict.fromkeys(next(f, "") for line in f if "CA002" in line)
    out.writelines(filtered.iterkeys()) # .keys() python3
```

For future reference you can call set on a file object. `set(file)` would be the same as `set(file.readlines())`. `a+` opening a file for `reading` and `writing/appending`, if you want to create a file and just write use `w`.

Comment: With `OrderedDict.fromkeys` you can preserve the order! nice!

Comment: @Kasra, just a little more concise way to do it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham by the way I'm using python 2.6, it doesn't support multiple context managers

Answer (score 0):

Since your repeated values just appear continuously and I assumed that read values from **input.dat** are already sorted, you can do a simple thing like this:

```
written = ''
with open("Reference.txt", "a+") as f :
   with open("input.dat") as fi:
        for line in fi:
            if "CA002" in line:
                current = fi.next()
                if current != written:
                    f.write(current)
                    written = current
```

So it only write the value if it different with the value that has just written before.